# Are TCP sessions persistent when switching to inkognito browsing?

Tags: browser, tcp

if you open a website and then follow a link within the same site trough opening it in an inkognito mode, do the browsers keep their connection on a tcp level (as they would per https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-8.1 ?

Comment: RFC2616 is quite old and wouldn't tell you much about how modern browsers work. For instance, "A
   single-user client SHOULD NOT maintain more than 2 connections with
   any server or proxy" hasn't been followed by any mainstream browser for years (I think most have gone to 6 or 10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never heard about a standard about inconginto mode but browsers certainly should not reuse TCP connections from non-incognito mode in incognito one. I've just checked Firefox and Chrome. They open new TCP connections.

You can check it by yourself. Write a dump by Wireshark. Apply HTTP filter. Find a request. Apply "Follow TCP stream" context menu. You will see the whole TCP stream. It's easy to read.